# Solving initial value problem with delta function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Use the Laplace transform to solve the following initial value problem:
>   $$y''+4y = 3\delta(t-\pi), \quad y(0)=0,  y'(0)=0$$

I solve the equation based on what I learned in class, my answer is $(3/2)H(t-\pi)\sin(2t-\pi)$.

Professor's given answer is $(3/2)H(t-\pi)\sin(2t-2\pi)$

Did I make a mistake somewhere, or did my professor mistype the number $2$ in front of $\pi$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the initial conditions are something like $y(0) = y'(0) = 0$, we have

$$Y(s) = \frac{3}{2} e^{-\pi s} \frac{2}{s^2 + 4} \implies y(t) = \frac 3 2 H(t - \pi) \sin\big(2(t - \pi)\big)$$

where we have used the fact that $$\mathcal{L}\big(\sin(2t)\big) = \frac{2}{s^2 + 4}.$$

Hence, the professor's answer is correct.